# Google Apps Script event object is undefined in my Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

The problem is that my function receives an undefined event object. Can you tell me what's the problem?

Here's the function:

```
function onGmailMessageOpen(event) {
  const { accessToken, messageId } = event.commonEventObject;
  return buildCard();
}
```

Here's the appsscript.json manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Contacts",
    "logoUrl": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/dfdvUXkVaB8yVTsrnuFagTy9YDvEPz3jqJWhFNpxKbbJhq7kdOTkwfoSEtn4VBOb9tZ_B6DT3Q-L4wU5Cw-FCcYY4fISn29OkcBOCwp69q5GxI4AM2WXHHk6kaQtgA",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessageOpen"
      }
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#547dbf"
  },
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the custom function?

Comment: function onGmailMessageOpen(event) {
    const { accessToken, messageId } = event.commonEventObject;
    return buildCard();           
}

Comment: Can you show us more context ?

Comment: How are you running the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function declaration `function onGmailMessageOpen(event) {/**/}` tells that your function is designed to receive a properly populated `event` object.

Do not run the code directly in the script editor. If you do, the `event` object will not be properly populated, causing the error you mention.

What you should do is let Google's code call the function when the user opens a message in the UI. When called like this, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects) will be properly populated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really tried to test the events via a sandbox.